# IE 9 Browser and Document modes change everytime on restart?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I have some CSS that works only when the Browser and Document mode is et to IE 9 standards. 
However, everytime I close it and open it, it reverts back to IE 9 Compatibilty Browser mode and IE 8 standards Document mode and all the CSS does not render. 
What can I do to force these settings permanently?
Thanks

Comment: Hm, I have no experience with this, but I suspect there is a meta tag on the page or a response header or something, that is enforcing this behavior... Check the `<head>` in the source code of the web-page, and also check the response headers via the dev tools...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas What exactly should I be looking for under <head>?

Comment: Something like this: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">`. The "X-UA-Compatible" value may also be located in the response header. Read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to change IE8 to IE9 in this tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

Thanks to  Šime Vidas!